# Angular 2 Service - Subscribing Does Not Save Data?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am writing an Angular 2 application with components that represent pages. When I navigate to a new component/page, I also want to keep track of which component/page I was on previously. I am achieving this through a service.

When I subscribe to the service in my component constructor, it looks like my data is being saved to a property correctly. However, if I try to access this property later on, it says it is undefined. Why is this?

Scaled-down example: my two pages are page-one and page-two. page-one has a button that goes to page-two; page-two has a source-page property, which should store "page-one" as the value.

SOURCE CODE: history.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HistoryService {

  priorPage = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }
}
```

SOURCE CODE: page-one.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HistoryService } from '../services/history/history.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-one',
  templateUrl: './page-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-one.component.css']
})
export class PageOneComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private historyService: HistoryService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loadPageTwo() {
    this.historyService.priorPage.emit("page-one");
    this.router.navigate(['/pagetwo']);
  }
}
```

SOURCE CODE: page-one.component.html

```
<p>
  Welcome to Page1!
</p>
<button (click)="loadPageTwo()">Go To Page Two</button>
```

SOURCE CODE: page-two.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HistoryService } from '../services/history/history.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-two',
  templateUrl: './page-two.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-two.component.css']
})
export class PageTwoComponent implements OnInit {
  sourcePage: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private historyService: HistoryService) {
    this.historyService.priorPage.subscribe(
      (priorPage: string) => {
        this.sourcePage = priorPage;
        console.log('priorPage = ' + priorPage);
        console.log('sourcePage = ' + this.sourcePage);
      }
    );
   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  loadPageOne() {
    this.router.navigate(['/pageone']);
  }

  logSource() {
    console.log('logSource: sourcePage = ' + this.sourcePage);
  }

}
```

SOURCE CODE: page-two.component.html

```
<p>
  Welcome to Page2!
</p>
<p>You came from {{source}}</p>
<button (click)="loadPageOne()">Go To Page One</button>
<button (click)="logSource()">Log Source</button>
```

The output when I navigate from page-one to page-two and then hit the "Log Source" button is:

```
priorPage = page-one
sourcePage = page-one
logSource: sourcePage = undefined
```

How do I update this so that the sourcePage property retains the value?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it from the code you shared but just making sure, you are not using ```ChangeDetection.OnPush``` are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are emitting the value first and then navigating to the page. Therefore the component is getting created after value has already been emitted. Check if your `console.log` statements are getting executed.

Why not keep the `priorPage` in `HistoryService`?

History Service:

```
export class HistoryService {

  priorPage: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Page One Component

```
export class PageOneComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private historyService: HistoryService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loadPageTwo() {
    this.historyService.priorPage = "page-one";
    this.router.navigate(['/pagetwo']);
  }
}
```

Page two component

```
export class PageTwoComponent implements OnInit {
  sourcePage: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private historyService: HistoryService) {
        this.sourcePage = this.historyService.priorPage;

   }
```